# Make Error (trying to install openOCD)

Tags: pi-2, sudo, make, makefile

I am having issues installing openOCD. I followed this [tutorial](https://movr0.com/2016/09/02/use-raspberry-pi-23-as-a-jtagswd-adapter/) and everything works perfectly until I try to make the file. I am getting these warnings and errors:

```
Makefile:4314: warning: overriding recipe for target 'check-recursive'
Makefile:3729: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'check-recursive'
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openocd'
Makefile:4314: warning: overriding recipe for target 'check-recursive'
Makefile:3729: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'check-recursive'
Making all in jimtcl
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openocd/jimtcl'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openocd/jimtcl'
Making all in src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openocd/src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openocd/src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink'
Making all in libjaylink
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openocd/src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink/libjaylink'
make[4]: Warning: File '/usr/include/stdc-predef.h' has modification time 2294104 s in the future
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC --silent  --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0  -g -O2 -MT libjaylink_la-buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libjaylink_la-buffer.Tpo -c -o libjaylink_la-buffer.lo `test -f 'buffer.c' || echo './'`buffer.c
rm: cannot remove '.libs/libjaylink_la-buffer.o': Permission denied
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create .libs/libjaylink_la-buffer.o: Permission denied
Makefile:505: recipe for target 'libjaylink_la-buffer.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [libjaylink_la-buffer.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openocd/src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink/libjaylink'
Makefile:468: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openocd/src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink'
Makefile:374: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openocd/src/jtag/drivers/libjaylink'
Makefile:3729: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openocd'
Makefile:1599: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried to Google these errors, but nothing worked. I also tried to make a clean install and reinstalling some packages. But I still get the same errors.

Could you help me correct these errors or guide me to the right path?

Comment: You may try to compile on only one CPU, as multi-core compiling isn't reliable. Use `make` instead of `make -j4`. I would also try to run `sudo make`, wich may be a bad practice, but can quicly solve the permission issues.

Comment: Ignore that; this has nothing to do with `-j4`, which is totally fine and reliable.  This *is* obviously about permissions issues.  Using `sudo` will get around that, but it seems a little strange there's a need for that if you are running this as `pi` from `/home/pi` or a subdirectory .

Comment: Multi-core compilation errors may occurs (race condition) but indeed, the problem seems to come from wrong permissions.

Comment: @goldilocks thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have tried make, sudo make, and sudo make j4; but still get the same error. And yes, I am running this as pi. I also tried reflashing the OS and reinstalling openOCD, but it did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What are the permissions for `.libs`

Comment: @yamboy1 how can I check those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem following the installation steps mentioned in this [tutorial](https://log2.ch/2014/stm32-and-jtag-via-raspberry/).

From the tutorial, I did the following (after reflashing Raspian to my SD):

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep openocd
$ sudo apt-get install git
$ git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/openocd/code openocd
$ cd openocd
$ ./bootstrap 
$ ./configure --enable-bcm2835gpio 
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

I do not know how or why this worked for me, but it did. I now have openOCD working in my Pi.